# Add String with html tags to open xml word

Tags: c#, html, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am trying to add a html formatted text to a Open xml Text. 
How can I apply the formatting already present in the text?

I apply the text as following:

```
TextElement.Text = formattedString;
```

where FormattedString contains the following:

```
<p>test<br/>test2<ul><li>item1</li><li>item2<li2></p>
```

At the moment it simply inserts the text as it is with the tags into the word document. 
How can I tell Open XML SDK to add the string with the right format?

Comment: A wild guess: XML encode it (converting the five reserved XML characters (>, <, &, and single and double quotes) to the appropriate encoded characters).  A better way would be to download the OpenXML Productivity Tool from the Microsoft site, create a document (using Word) containing your test line (above), save it, then open the document in the Productivity Tool and use the "Reflect" option to see what code gets produced.

Comment: Is there a way to specify the type of text as "html"? Please see the properties of "TextElement" to find out. Please see if the link below is helpful: http://www.ludovicperrichon.com/create-a-word-document-with-openxml-and-c/

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an [`AlternativeFormatImportPart`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.packaging.alternativeformatimportpart?view=openxml-2.8.1) which contains your HTML, then you need to add an [`AltChunk`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.altchunk?view=openxml-2.8.1) to your document and give it the `id` of the `AlternativeFormatImportPart`.

The following code creates a file from scratch with your HTML in it. Note that HTML fragments don't appear to be supported so I've added `<html>` tags to your HTML snippet.

```
using (var document = WordprocessingDocument.Create(filename, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
{
    document.AddMainDocumentPart();
    document.MainDocumentPart.Document = new Document();
    document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body = new Body();

    //create a memory stream with the HTML required
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<html><p>test<br/>test2<ul><li>item1</li><li>item2<li2></p><html>"));

    //Create an alternative format import part on the MainDocumentPart
    AlternativeFormatImportPart altformatImportPart = document.MainDocumentPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(AlternativeFormatImportPartType.Html);

    //Add the HTML data into the alternative format import part
    altformatImportPart.FeedData(ms);

    //create a new altChunk and link it to the id of the AlternativeFormatImportPart
    AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
    altChunk.Id = document.MainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(altformatImportPart);

    // add the altChunk to the document
    document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Append(altChunk);

    document.Save();
}
```

This produces the following output:

[image]